# Add tick marks to plotted line (not axes) in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am making a linegraph and want to add log tick marks of a third variable (time) along the plotted line. Below is a simplfied version of my input, the reality is less neat.

```
input_x = [0, 0.5, 1, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5]
input_y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 , 90, 100]
input_time = [11, 30, 40, 250, 356, 488, 571, 765, 823, 1002]
```

I then interpolate these:

```
time_range = [i for i in range(0.1, 2.5, 10)]
interpolate1 = interp1d(input_time, input_x, kind='linear')
y = interpolate1(time_range)
interpolate2 = interp1d(input_time, input_y, kind='linear')
x = interpolate2(time_range)
```

And define the time ticks that I want to show as log ticks along the line plot:

```
time_ticks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]
```

Then find the value of x and y at these times:

```
tick_array = [min(zip(time_range, x, y), key=lambda i:abs(i[0]-val)) for val in time_ticks]
tick_x = [line[1] for line in tick_array]
tick_y = [line[2] for line in tick_array]
```

And plot the line graph of my x and y values:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
```

I know I could then plot at the time_tick points:

```
plt.plot(tick_x, tick_y, '|')
```

But this just plots vertical dashes, and I want them to be perpendicular to the plotted line.  Is there a function in python that will do this for me?

Comment: have you tried "_" instead of "|" for your __markers__? http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html

Comment: I have, but my line plot isn't as simple as the one I've given in my pseudo-code, it is horizontal, then curves upward so neither '_' or '|' work.  I think I need a way of telling the markers to be perpendicular to the line plot, but I've no idea how to do that

Comment: why not using a bigger marker with a different color like first "-b" to plot a blue line then "ro" add red circles?

Answer (score 6):

For the late arrivers here, I just stumbled upon this [blog post](https://scipython.com/blog/adding-ticks-to-a-matplotlib-line/) (Nov 2016), which seems to be doing exactly what you want: markers perpendicular to the line plot.

[image]